# How to get the tables used by a query with OdbcConnection and c#

Tags: c#, odbc

I have the next code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var conn = new OdbcConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = textBox_ConnectionString.Text;
        conn.Open();
        var cmd = new OdbcCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = textBox_Query.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;


        var datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (datareader.Read()) {
            var v1 = datareader.GetProviderSpecificFieldType(0);
            var v2 = datareader.GetFieldType(0);
            var v4 = datareader.GetDataTypeName(0);

        }
        conn.Close();
        datareader.Close();
    }
```

And, given a query, for example:

```
select table1.field1,table1.field2,table2.field3,..
       from table1,table2 where table1.field1=table2.field1
```

, i wish to know the name of the column, the type of the row and the column of the result. Right now, i have the name (field1,field2..) and the type (varchar,int..) for each column.

Is it possible to obtain the table related with the column result?.

ps:i am using odbc because i wish for a database agnostic solution.

Comment: Did you already look into [OdbcDataReader.GetSchemaTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.getschematable.aspx)? I guess it should give you the table each column.

Comment: I tried and it return the field empty. However with ADODB it works, so i think that it is easy to move to ADODB